# How to delete item in Angular and PHP

Tags: php, angular

I want to delete my item using 'srno' in my angular project. I have passed the 'srno' to the URL but it shows some error.

I checked my PHP code using postman, It is successfully worked.

I can't recognize my .ts file syntax error.

Error :

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost/angular_crud/delete.php?srno=srno", ok: false, …}
```

delete.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

interface Delete{
  srno: String;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-delete',
  templateUrl: './delete.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./delete.component.css']
})
export class DeleteComponent implements OnInit {

  delete: Delete[] = [];
  srno : String;

  myControl1 = new FormControl();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, public route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  personDelete(){
    this.srno = this.myControl1.value;

    var url = "http://localhost/angular_crud/delete.php?srno=srno";

    this.http.get<Delete[]>(url).subscribe(data => {
    this.delete = data;
    console.log(data);
   })
  }
}
```

This is the delete.component.html

```
<h1 style="text-align: center">Adding Items here!</h1>
<div>
<p>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form_field">
        <mat-label>Serial Number</mat-label>
        <input [formControl]="myControl1" matInput placeholder="Enter the Serial number">
        <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
        <mat-hint>ie : 787</mat-hint>
    </mat-form-field>
</p>
</div>

<button (click)="personDelete()" mat-raised-button color="warn" class="btn">Delete</button>
```

This is the delete.php

```
<?php 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,DELETE');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Header: H-Requested-With");

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "", "savedata");

$srno = $_GET["srno"];

if($con->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}

$sql = "DELETE FROM savedata WHERE srno='$srno'";

if($con->query($sql) === TRUE){
    echo "Record delete successfully";
}
else{
    echo "Error deleting record: ". $con->error;
}

$con->close();
?>
```

Comment: did you debug at php side?

Comment: PHP code is completely worked and I have tested it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API doesn't return JSON. Try

```
this.http
    .get(url, {responseType: 'text'})
    .subscribe(data => {
       console.log(data);
    });
```

Comment: URL should be,    var url = "http://localhost/angular_crud/delete.php?srno=" + this.srno;